# Jest - "testMatch" doesn't seem to be correctly matching with my file

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm currently trying to use `testMatch` to match test files:

```
"testMatch": [
      "./src/__tests__/*.js",
      "./src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js"
]
```

And this is what my file structure looks like:

```
src/
    -__test__/
        -textInput.test.js
package.json
package-lock.json
README.MD
```

For some reason, it keeps telling me this:
[image: error]

Have I made a mistake in my regex? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string) says default testMatch regEx is:

```
[ 
  "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)", 
  "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x)" 
]
```

Can you check these values?